# Navigation Drawer not working in Android 2.3.5 with android 4.0 supportive library

Tags: android, android-resources, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, navigation-drawer

I am going to implement the Navigation Drawer in my application. I come with the sample demo of the Developer site for same. Here is the link of [android official- sample code](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip).

I have download that demo and it works fine. But now if i am going to run that in to the Android 2.3.5 then it get crashed. Its not working there. I have also Try with to add library of ActionBarSherlock in to project and try that But now i am getting recource error like below:

```
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1577)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1776)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:701)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:758)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1629)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1407)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7299)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1177)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1897)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    ... 35 more
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1907)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1985)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:466)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:459)
06-28 10:14:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    ... 38 more
06-28 10:14:43.500: W/ActivityManager(1670):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.MainActivity
06-28 10:14:43.507: E/(1670): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

So, Please can anybudy help me? What to do if i need to implement Navigation Drawer in the andorid having 2.3.5? I know that is possible as i have downloaded Google Music App which having Navigation Drawer and work great in my android 2.3.5.

Comment: The error is `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable` - post your XML so we can help you.

Comment: ok wait for the updated question.

Comment: instead of putting all the xml, can you please check it in the link i have given in Question? I am using same demo but in android 2.3.5

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Do you have any sollution?